# Module dependencies issues co-developing two separate go modules

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm creating a [small utility](https://github.com/janpfeifer/VideoControls), let's call it **A**, for which I require a small change to another [go project](https://github.com/blackjack/webcam), let's call it **B**.

First I forked **B** into [**B_forked**](https://github.com/janpfeifer/webcam), and created the needed PR. The author hasn't reviewed it yet, which is fine, no hurry.

But I would like to leave **A** working with my version **B_forked** for the time being. More than that I would like to be able to co-develop both (edit files and make them pick up each others changes, as opposed to having **A** stuck to a version of **B**/**B_forked**).

So I edited **A** to import **B_forked** and wrote the following in my `~/Projects/A/go.mod`:

```
module A

go 1.15

require (
    ... # Other packages
)

replace B_forked => ../B_forked
```

And in **B_forked** I entered (the version number was generated automatically by go) the following `~/Projects/B_forked/go.mod`:

```
module B_forked

go 1.15

require (
    B v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
    ... # Other packages
)

replace B => ./
```

In my **B_forked** version I don't want to replace all `import B/...` in the code with `import B_forked/...` (since I want the changes to be included in a PR to **B** later on). That's why I use the `replace` rule here.

Somehow this is not working, and I can't figure out why. Building **B_forked** seems to work:

```
$ cd ~/Projects/B_forked
$ go build
$
```

But when I try to compile **A**, I get:

```
$ cd ~/Projects/A
$ go build

go: found github.com/janpfeifer/webcam in github.com/janpfeifer/webcam v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: github.com/janpfeifer/webcam@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 requires
        github.com/blackjack/webcam@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

- `janpfeifer/webcam` == **B_forked**
- `blackjack/webcam` == **B**
- The version number for **B**, that is `blackjack/webcam`, was picked by go itself, when I built **B_forked**

I'm probably misunderstanding the underlying abstraction of go modules (by now I spent much more time on modules than on the simple code itself). Any ideas how to set this up ? Maybe there is a much easier way to roll that I'm not aware ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I probably should have been explicit about the following: I own project **A** (and **B_forked**), but I don't own or have write permissions on project **B**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through answers and comments (thx @kostix, @volker) and experimenting, what seemed to work best in my case was:

Fork **B** into **B_forked**, and have 2 branches in **B_forked**:

- In branch **b1** is the one I used to create github's PR.
- In branch **b2** I changed all the self-imports of **B** to **B_forked**. After that I used **b2** to co-developed with **A**. I `git cherry-pick` the changes submitted back to branch **b1**.

In **A** I imported **B_forked**, and at `go.mod` I set the version to the HEAD of **b2** branch, so it can be built by others while the PR doesn't make into repository **B**.

During development I add in **A**'s `go.mod` a *replace* rule from **B_forked** to its local disk directory, so changes in **B_forked** are seen immediately in **A**.

Once the PR to **B** is in, I'll change back **A**'s imports to **B**.

Answer (score -1):

If you "fork" a repository containing a Go package or a Go module you create something entirely unrelated to the original. Depending on the details you might not even be able to compile the "fork" (not even the unmodified "fork") and the "fork" might not work.

Rule of thumb: **Never** fork a Go package or Go module.

> In my B_forked version I don't want to replace all import B/... in the code with import B_forked/...

You **must** as explained above. B_forked is completely unrelated to B. You **must** rewrite all imports or add replace directives for all imports. The word word "must" is chosen carefully here: You really must, there is no tricking or being clever here, especially

> That's why I use the replace rule here.

won't work. That simply is not how Go modules (or packages) work. Identitiy of modules is based on the module name  and identity of a package on its import path (which is prefixed by its containing module name).

The main problem stems from "forking". Just don't do that! You cannot work reliable and convenient on a fork. No way. No replace-directive magic will help. You must not fork.

Do a simple `git clone` instead. Like this you get a proper copy of the module/packages. Work on that clone. Add replace directives to your project A pointing to your local clone (not a "fork"!). Like this B still builds properly, no need for replace-magic or import path rewriting and A will pick up your local, modified copy of B.

> since I want the changes to be included in a PR to B later on

Okay. For a Github-PR you need a fork, but this fork needs to exist only on Github.
Do the following:

0. You already cloned B and worked on that. Keep that.
1. Fork B in the Github GUI.
2. Add that fork as an additional remote to your clone.
3. When you want  to create a PR: Push from your clone to your additional remote fork and make the PR.
4. Never even try to compile the "fork". The "fork" exists only on Github to make PRs. All your work is done on the actual code of B.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 

It seems odd that the Go modules framework won't be friendly to forks. I have the feeling there is more nuance to Go modules than what I read in [Go module blog post](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

But I needed the fork for two reasons:

1. As you pointed out for Github-PR

2. Because while the PR is not accepted, I wanted my project A to work with the fork.

But in this case, if I'm interpreting you right, I will have to properly fork, by rewriting all the import lines within my fork to use itself, is that right ?

Comment: @Jan, yes because «Identitiy of modules is based on the module name and identity of a package on its import path (which is prefixed by its containing module name).»

Comment: Still, [this](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) states that you can replace a module with another using purely its import path, but the import path the target (replacement) module declares in its `go.mod` must be the the original one (of the one being replaced).

Comment: @kostix  Thanks. I still would like to "replace" the module identity in go.mod, and have the magic translate to all imports -- one easy place to "link" the module identity, without affecting the packages. If that doesn't work ... patience, I'll live with it :), but it feels it should be -- or I'm not understanding it why it shouldn't.

Comment: @kostix I think I understood now, thanks again. From the [description](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) "Regardless ..., if the replacement module has a go.mod file, its module directive must match ..."  And I'm trying to make my model serve both as B and B_forked simultaneously, and that won't work :\     I decided to work around by having two branches in my fork: b1 to generate Github's PRs; b2 where I search&replaced all the imports to my B_forked and hence it can be used directly, and developed with. Later I cherry-picks the CLs back to b1. I'll write up an answer summarizin